# How to include richeditor styles in October Cms?

Tags: wysiwyg, octobercms

When using rich editor output block already have class names. But there is no styles for them in the client. I'm currently using demo theme to explore.

I tried aligning image in the rich editor, but it had no effect on the page. So I added "fr-view" class to the blog post container and also manually downloaded and included froala_style.min.css. Now it is working fine, but it fells like a workaround. Could this styles be included right from the admin ui or theme configuration?